# Haskell Function that Compares the Items of Two lists

Tags: list, haskell, compare

Im writing a Haskell function called myElems

that takes two lists of values and returns true if all the values in
the first list are in the second list. E.g., `myElems "db" "abcd"` should return `true` whereas `myElems [1,2] [0,1,3,4]` should return `false`.

`myElem` function is like this

```
myElem n [] = False
myElem n (x:xs) = if n == x then True else myElem n xs
```

this function works just fine but when I try to apply it to myElems function which has this form

```
myElems xs [] = False
myElems [] ys = False
myElems (x:xs) (y:ys) = if myElem y xs /= myElem x ys then False else myElems (tail xs) (tail ys)
```

it doesn't work at all.

Comment: It's a trivial homework problem, and while the OP posted his attempt to solve it, he clearly didn't spend any time thinking about *why* it didn't work. Check out his second line: `myElems [] ys = False`. He would have caught the blatant logic error if he'd put thought into it; before even getting to the nonsense in the third line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean

```
myElems [] ys = True
myElems (x:xs) ys = if myElem x ys then myElems xs ys else False
```

Comment: @Quuxplusone - your diagnosis was correct, but then you give the "Don't bother to think, SO users will be glad to do your homework" medicine? Instead of, for example, asking: if myElem [] xs is False, what is the element in the first list that is not in the second list?

Answer (score 2):

I know it's not the exact answer, but how about what [Learn You Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/modules) book recommends:

```
import qualified Data.Set as Set  
Set.fromList [2,3,4] `Set.isSubsetOf` Set.fromList [1,2,3,4,5]
```